# Not removing the Time Components from NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I need to remove the time components from NSDate for instance: I have the value of '2012-08-12 22:15:54 +00000' but I got the value '2012-08-12 03:00:00 +00000'

The Code I am Using is:

```
NSDate* getNDateOfWeek(int week, int day) {

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *comp = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:now];
    [comp setWeekday:day];
    [comp setWeek: week];
    [comp setHour:0];
    NSDate *resultDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comp];
    return resultDate;

}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be trying to achieve a different result but if you are simply looking for 'todays' date then what about something like:

```
// Output -> 'Mon, Jan 16, 2012'
- (NSString *)todaysDate
{
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d Y"];    
   return [dateFormat stringFromDate:[[NSDate alloc] init]];
}
```